# Подскажите хороший менеджер двойной загрузки

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование

Добрый день.

Есть ноутбук ACER Pentium четырехъядерный довольно новый (CPU N3540 покупал полтора года назад). На нем стояла Windows-8 после покупки она проапгрейдилась до Windows-10-64 Home Edition. Теперь мне нужно параллельно с Windows поставить Linux. Но так, чтобы Windows не слетел(а). Когда-то давно я работал с разными менеджерами двойных загрузок. Но тот опыт был резко негативным. Операционки слетали, менеджеры подвисали и даже портили диск и вообще работать было невозможно. Подскажите, как сейчас обстоит дело на этом фронте. Какие есть сейчас хорошие и работоспособные менеджеры двойных загрузок? Почему-то в БИОСе ноутбука нет возможности указать, что на ноутбуке стоят несколько ОС. Хотя разговоры о том, что менеджеры двойных загрузок будут встроены в БИОСы я слышал.

Спасибо.

Comment: grub работает как всегда. То, что Вы называете "встроенное в биос" - это новомодная штука, которая называется uefi. операционки от груба не слетают, (но вот винда при инсталляции може его снести), диск не портят. Но главное, вначале разберитесь, у вас gpt или нет.

Comment: @KoVadim Я боюсь, что если начать ставить grub поверх Windows, то Windows слетит. У кого есть опыт установки grub поверх Windows? Там все нормально будет? Тем более что у меня ноут а не десктоп а в ноутах железо часто нестандартное.

Comment: "ставить груб поверх windows" - это неправильная фраза. Не получиться. Груб состоит из двух частей: загрузчика (он там несколько сот байт и он перекрывает виндовый) и собственно груб, который ставиться внутрь линукса. Поэтому, максимум - перетрете загрузчик

Comment: @KoVadim Так вот я и боюсь, что когда перекроется виндовый загрузчик, то после этого я винду не смогу запустить. И останусь и без винды, и без линукса. И восстановить винду не смогу, потому что со скрытого раздела винта мне нулевую копию вин-8 удалили при апгрейде до вин-10. :-(

Comment: груб умеет загружать винду. Но если боитесь, то может поставить линукс (или винду) в virtualbox и забыть о страхе?

Comment: @KoVadim Кстати, это идея. Подумаю. Хотя боксы тоже косые, всю систему от них ведет в сторону и потом от них никак не избавишься, особенно на винде.

Comment: Тогда Вам нужно два компа/ноутбука.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете спокойно работать в *Windows* & *Linux*, как ОС которые установлены параллельно на *HDD*, или можете в *Windows* установить *VirtualBox & VMware Workstation*, создать гостевую ОС *Linux*.

Работать с "виртуальной" ОС можно спокойно и практически полноценно (программирование, дизайн, верстка). Для начала, конечно же, рекомендую виртуальную машину, для ознакомления.

Если же Вы решите установить две ОС параллельно, то выделите разделы на жестком под каждую ОС отдельно - для *Linux OS* - /swap - 2 GB, корневой каталог / - min 20 GB, домашний каталог /home - все остальное пространство. Под *Windows* все просто, - раздел под диск С: рекомендую 60 Gb, а так на Ваше усмотрение.

Далее, сначала установите *Windows*, а затем *Linux*. При установке *Linux*, загрузчик grub "увидит" что параллельно установлена *Windows*, и укажет это в своих настройках. При перезагрузке Вы сможете выбирать какую ОС загружать.

Самый верный и стабильный вариант. Если же наоборот, загрузчик *Windows* затрет загрузчик grub, и тогда придется его восстанавливать.